# Change color of selected cell in a gridview _RowCommand()

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a Gridview of 10 rows and 3 columns. I want to change the color of a cell when it is clicked. Then if the user clicks it again, remove the color.

By this code I already have my row number stored in `index`.

```
Protected Sub GridView6_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView6.RowCommand
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
                    // Here I want to change my selected cell color
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt get u, I just create a rowcommand event so I can do some other things too like "If e.CommandName = "All" then ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a trick. I am not sure if it is a right way but yeah it worked for me.

```
Protected Sub GridView6_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView6.RowCommand
    Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    Dim r As GridViewRow = GridView6.Rows(index)
    Dim cell1 As Button = r.Cells(0).Controls(0)
    Dim c1 As String = RTrim(cell1.Text)
    Dim cell2 As Button = r.Cells(1).Controls(0)
    Dim c2 As String = RTrim(cell2.Text)
    Dim cell3 As Button = r.Cells(2).Controls(0)
    Dim c3 As String = RTrim(cell3.Text)

    Dim cellname As String = RTrim(e.CommandName)

     If c1 = cellname Then
        If cell1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.OliveDrab Then
            cell1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Linen

        Else
            cell1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.OliveDrab

        End If
    End If
    // AND same for C2 and C3
```

It worked both way to color and discolor ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Should work

```
Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
If (GridView1.Rows(index).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Aqua) Then
    GridView1.Rows(index).BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
Else
    GridView1.Rows(index).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Aqua
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but It will change the selected row color, and I just want the selected cell color

Answer (score -1):

If this is a webpage(since you tagged asp.net) I would do it client sided, with javascript.

Or else the page would be reloaded on-select and reselect.

Add the cells to a class, and put an click event to them. 
Either changing the css background or adding them to a new class.

Comment: I dont know why but I cant put click event maybe because its databound gridview.

Comment: Were you able to put the table cells in a class?